# Map modifier+mouse button to key combination

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I have a Kensington ExpertMouse with 4 buttons (LButton, RButton, MButton, Xbutton1)

I want to map modifier+mouse botton -> key combination

ie: Shift + LButton -> ctrl + c

I tried X-Mouse Button Control but as far as I can tell it is not possible.
I understand this can be achieved with AHK but that seems like an over kill.

Any other option ?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found KeyManager (https://atnsoft.com/?src=keymanager&ver=1.14.420) that seems to do the job